# Javascripts not working on SSR with Angular 11 Universal

Tags: javascript, angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

The SSR part is working, and it is reachable by localhost:4000, including our stylesheets etc. The package.json's relevant part is:

```
"dev:ssr": "ng run project:serve-ssr",
"serve:ssr": "node dist/project/server/main.js",
"build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run project:server:production",
"prerender": "ng run project:prerender"
```

But the problem is, the served website doesn't contain our javascript file in the body (eg. main.1234567.js) angular.json's relevant part is below:

```
{
  "server": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
    "options": {
      "outputPath": "dist/project/server",
      "main": "server.ts",
      "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json"
    },
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        "outputHashing": "media",
        "fileReplacements": [
          {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
          }
        ],
        "sourceMap": false,
        "optimization": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I check the dist/project/browser, I can see the index.html with the javascript files, also the javascript files themselves are in the directory.

But when I run "npm run serve:ssr", then the served website is missing all these javascript files.

What am I missing here, should I add a configuration to angular.json to include these files?

Comment: Does it work if you generate a clean project then add universal schematics?

Comment: Is there any js files referenced in the rendered html? If yes, what are the links?